# Property of linear multidimensional function?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Is it true that if $f(x,y)$ is a linear on both x and y

$f(ax,by) = af(x,by)+bf(ax,y)$?

Comment: No, this is not going to be true in general. Take $a=b=1$. Then $f(x,y)=2f(x,y)$ implying $f(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y)$ yet there are multilinear functions which are not identically $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

If $f(x,y)$ is linear in $x$ than
$$f(ax,y)=af(x,y)$$
and if is linear in $y$ than
$$f(x,by)=bf(x,y)$$
so
$$f(ax,by)=abf(x,y)$$